# How to transform code with turning value to using wheels only

Tags: python, math, robotics

So I have been working on a Robot and followed a tutorial... I've reached certain point where I need to change a line in code but have no idea how to convert the code so it would work for me.

On tutorial a guy has a RaspberryPi Code:

```
motor.move(0.20(speed of both whells),-curveVal*sens(turning),0.05(duration of moving))
```

My Robobo .moveWhellsByTime function:

```
rob.moveWheelsByTime(20(speed of left wheel), 20(speed of right wheel), 0.05(duration of moving)
```

Now my question is how can I convert `-curveVal*sens` to be used by my function that has wheels only and no turning value?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I misunderstood the question, but I guess all you want is for the wheels not to be angled? If you give 0 to 'turning' the problem is solved

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).